How to get Net Promoter Score per quarter
I have a fields
id SERIAL,
score INTEGER,
notes TEXT,
nps_datetime TIMESTAMP
The score field is a value between 1 and 5.
I get the NPS with this query
SELECT CAST(((
  SUM(CASE WHEN score BETWEEN 4 AND 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 1.0 -
  SUM(CASE WHEN score BETWEEN 1 AND 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  ) / COUNT(*) * 100) AS int) NPS FROM net_promoter_score
WHERE score IS NOT NULL;

I managed to get the quarterly count of each score, but cannot get the overall NPS for each quarter.
I tried using this:
SELECT score, notes, extract(quarter FROM nps_datetime) AS quarter, count(*)
FROM net_promoter_score
GROUP BY score, notes, extract(quarter from nps_datetime)
ORDER BY extract(quarter from nps_datetime) ASC;

How could I get the NPS for each quarter?
